# Lucas Number Equivalent of the Pisano Period?

Tags: number-theory, notation, modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

I'm doing some work with the Pisano Period, and it's leading to also talk about the Lucas numbers $mod \ m$, and their period. Is there a specific notation already designated? Sticking with using a Greek letter that has something to do with what the function is named after, I was thinking $\lambda(m)$.

Comment: ...not to derail your work too much, but won't this be exactly the same as the Pisano Period?  Since the Lucas numbers can be written as a linear combination of the Fibonaccis and vice versa, any period of one is a period of the other...

Comment: Haha, if that's true, then you'd be saving me more work, not derailing my current work. Unfortunately, it's not true. $\pi(10) = 60$ while $\lambda(10) = 12$.

Comment: Well, since $L_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$, if we have $F_k\equiv F_{k+p}$ then $L_{k+p}=F_{k+p-1}+F_{k+p+1}$ $\equiv F_{k-1}+F_{k+1}$ $\equiv L_k$.  A similar formula will go the other way, but since the Lucas-to-Fibonacci conversion involves a division by 5, it might be a little bit trickier if $m$ is divisible by 5...

Comment: Whoops. :-) Though it is in fact correct that $\lambda(m)|\pi(m)$ for all $m$ by the Fibonacci-to-Lucas formula, and that they'll be equal for all $m$ with $(m,5)=1$...

Comment: What do you mean $(m,5) = 1$?

Comment: That's just notation for 'the GCD of $m$ and $5$ is $1$' - or in other words, that $m$ isn't divisible by $5$.

Comment: Can you show me that Lucas-to-Fibonacci conversion that includes that division by 5 and proves that $\lambda(m)|\pi(m)$ bit?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12498/discussion-between-jshoe-and-steven-stadnicki)